# Simple PayPal Payment Form or Email Link

Tags: forms, paypal

I do all my accounting in Quickbooks Online and customers can pay invoices online.  However sometimes I need to accept a payment that isn't tied to one specific invoice.  I'd greatly appreciate it if someone can confirm which of these options are feasible and simplest/easiest way to implement.  I'd like to avoid a PayPal Payments Pro Subscription as I will rarely need this functionality but if that's the only way, then so be it.

1) Send the customer a link to a simple payment form where either they can enter any payment amount or it pre-populates with the requested amount. (I'd prefer not to have to code a payment form on my site.  I'd just like to do it with an iframe, framing in a PayPal hosted payment form.)

2) Create a payment request but email them the link to the request payment form myself rather than the request being mailed separately from PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the "Quickbooks Payment Request Wizard". it allows you to easily insert a PayPal payment button in e-mail versions of your QuickBooks invoices and estimates.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=xpt/Marketplaces/seller/QuickBooksPaymentWizardIntro-outside

A similar version of this tool allows you to embed a payment button into an Outlook email.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/payment_wizard_intro-outside

Both tools are free and require only a standard PayPal Business or Premier account.